# Finding x and y offset according to new screen resolution

Tags: java, android, canvas, coordinates, draw

I have an Android game where I need to draw an object based on coordinates chosen by the player. It is then sent to the opponent. I need to draw the object in the same position on the new screen. This is what I have right now

```
float x = originalX;
float y = originalY;

x *= myWidth / originalWidth;
y *= myHeight / originalHeight;

drawRect(x, y, x+width, y+width);
```

It doesn't seem to work. Any guesses?

Comment: for starters you have a typo on last line, should it be y+width or y+height?

Comment: Also, are your width and height values ints or floats?  If ints, you may have a problem of the results of the division being rounded to 0 or 1.